# wsimport maven task not working

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, wsimport

I'm tring to import data from remote wsdl. I have written in maven simple code as below

```
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>generate-stubs1</id>
             <phase>process-classes</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>wsimport</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
                <packageName>com.sth.remote</packageName>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

And what is strange in behaviour of this script is that it works only the first time. After, for instance "clean install", java code from wsdl is not generated again. And in debug mode I'm getting this output:

```
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] The wsdl Directory is Q:\workspace\xxx\src\wsdl
[INFO] No WSDLs are found to process, Specify at least one of the following parameters: wsdlFiles, wsdlDirectory or wsdlUrls.
```

How to resolve this problem ?

**UPDATE:**

I have noticed that this task works in Eclipse background when I delete target directory and then refresh eclipse project so that eclipse would compile code and run this task but via direct invoking `mvn jaxws:wsimport` not.

**UPDATE 2:**

What else, it sems that script running via `mvn jaxws:wsimport` omit my configuration because if I change for instance staleFile

```
<staleFile>Q:\workspace\xxx\target\jaxws\stale2</staleFile>
```

I still have in info in debug that default path to staleFile is in use:

```
<staleFile default-value="${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale"/>
...
[DEBUG]   (f) staleFile = Q:\workspace\visasin-gwt\target\jaxws\stale
```

Does someone have some idea what is going on ? @dienerd solution not working for me

Answer (score 1):

i removed your

```
<id>generatestubs-1</id>
```

and this ran perfectly. i did a super simple pom w/ just a maven compiler & java.version 1.8. i'm not sure what you are doing but i'd take it back down to simple & add stuff in:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>wsimport</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
                <packageName>com.sth.remote</packageName>
             </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you running jaxws:wsimport task ? I'm asking because I've found that after make some changes in pom this task is running in the background and in fact generating java code but not via jaxws:wsimport ?! Am I doing this wrong ?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. But this line is spit out in the logs:

    [DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven plugin:2.5:wsimport (default)
    [DEBUG] Style:         Regular
    [DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Sorry maybe I wouldn't be precise in my previous comment. I noticed right after your answer that this task is running in background in eclipse, after I delete 'staleFile' (${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale) and also delete generated java WS code. And then when I save some (for instance just simple space) change in pom.xml, Eclipse run tasks in background so this jaxws-maven-plugin and others generates self codes. But via direct invoke jaxws:wsimport task this not work. Do you have some idea how to resolve this? Very thanks for your precious time